# Deluge 100% CPU

Tags: cpu, deluge

From time to time Deluge goes to 100% CPU with no apparent reason, (no active torrents). If I restart it the CPU goes to around 0%

Has anyone else encountered that?

---

**Edit:**

Lol, finally solved the bug (after some investigating). In short it appears it's caused by Deluge using twisted.internet.run() instead of gtk.main() for it's main loop, and then twisted.internet.run() [calling gobject.threads_init()](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=481569) internally, which sets a SIGCHLD handler, and ultimately it boils down to a [bug in PyGtk](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pygtk/+bug/708847) that is resoved by [this patch](http://git.gnome.org/browse/pygtk/commit/?id=4cbd3c031289775f365c247f949d91facac4ba82):

```
diff --git a/gtk/gtk.override b/gtk/gtk.override
index 75018f4..94309a6 100644
--- a/gtk/gtk.override
+++ b/gtk/gtk.override
@@ -1151,9 +1151,10 @@ pygtk_main_watch_check(GSource *source)
 #ifdef HAVE_PYSIGNAL_SETWAKEUPFD
     PySignalWatchSource *real_source = (PySignalWatchSource *)source;
     GPollFD *poll_fd = &real_source->fd;
-    int data_size = 0;
+    unsigned char dummy;
+    gssize ret;
     if (poll_fd->revents & G_IO_IN)
-        data_size = read(poll_fd->fd, 0, 1);
+        ret = read(poll_fd->fd, &dummy, 1);
 #endif
     state = pyg_gil_state_ensure();
```

Now Deluge works fine, and I understand that this patch fixes a similar bug in other programs that use PyGtk as well.

Comment: Bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/deluge/+bug/660365

Comment: When you have problems with a program like this you need to have some basic information like: What version of Ubuntu are you using? What version of Deluge are you using? Without this most basic info, we're shooting in the dark.

Comment: @CYREX, thanks for the answer, I read about the bug (it was a duplicate btw), but had forgotten to come here and mark your answer as the correct.

Comment: Do not worry. Not helping for the points as primary reason but for the community as the first reason.

Comment: @satuon Can you add your final solution as an answer so you can mark it solved (so we can also vote on it), thanks!

Comment: @jorge-castro The 'Answer Your Question' button doesn't work for me, I click on it and nothing happens.

Comment: The actual bug is now fixed in Natty: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pygtk/+bug/664920

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a bug that the Deluge developers have blamed on a GTK+ control they use for displaying files. In short the workaround is to just not use the file pane and not to use the "open folder" context menu option.

`deluge-web` has a separate bug that also causes high CPU but this is officially fixed in the latest version available from [their website](http://deluge-torrent.org).

Answer (score 2):

The Deluge Forum has more detail about this problem, with links to bug reports and the patched debs for Natty and Maverick.

http://forum.deluge-torrent.org/viewtopic.php?p=152813#p152813